# Error save data in database

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have page that related with two table using the same database. the problem is when i try to save data into table #A, the data also save in table #B, i want the data only save in table #A but i got id from table #B.

Model for table #A

```
@JoinColumn(name = "VACANCYNAME", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne
private Vacancy vacancyname;
```

Model for table #B

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "vacancyname")
private List<ApplicantVacancy> applicantVacancyList;
```

jsp for table #A

```
<p> 
    <label>Vacancy Name</label>
    <form:input path="vacancyname.vacancyname" value="${param.name}" readonly="true"/>
</p>
```

jsp for table #B

```
<label>Webpage URL :<a href='http://localhost:8080/hrms/applicant/list.htm' target='new'> http://localhost:8080/hrms/applicantvacancy/index.htm</a></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your implementation, but this readOnly="true" dont't seems very well to persist the object in db.

Try to put it false.

```
<p> 
    <label>Vacancy Name</label>
    <form:input path="vacancyname.vacancyname" value="${param.name}" readonly="false"/>
</p>
```